# Memory increase from cellFromRowAtIndexPath in UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that creates a UITextView, then adds it to a cell.  No memory leaks were detected, but when running Instruments (Object Allocations), the Net memory is on a one-way trip to 18 MB, where it crashes.

My app constantly adds and deletes cells in the tableView datasource, but because the TextView is released, I can see no way memory could be piling up.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell==nil) {
    // Build cell
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UITextView *tv=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 95)];
tv.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16];

tv.text=@"My Cell Text";

[cell addSubview:tv];
[tv release];

return cell;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Instruments's Leaks template to debug this sort of thing. The Leaks instrument will show objects that still exist but nothing knows about; the ObjectAlloc instrument will show all objects, so you can drill down by class and by instance to see what might be holding onto them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add UITextView every time a cell is fetched. If it comes from cache, it already has one as a subview, so now it has two of them, then three, then four...

So only add them to *new* cells:

```
if (cell==nil) {
    // Build cell
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UITextView *tv=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 95)];
    tv.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16];
    tv.tag = 42; // Or whatever, if you don't want to use custom cells
    [cell addSubview:tv];
    [tv release];
}

UITextView *textView = (UITextView *) [cell viewWithTag:42];
textView.text=@"hi";
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great, except what if the dataSource is changed as in my case?  The cell still displays the cached data?

Comment: It will display whatever you set the text to, "hi" in this case... 

If you need different text, this is the place to set it - depending on the indexPath. If you need to change it while displayed, you need to reload the given indexPath, i.e. [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:... withAnimation:...];